# Count sum with trigger for delete/update/insert

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create trigger that updates price in a row. However this works fine whenever I am adding an amount, but it doesn't work whenever I am deleting the item or updating with smaller value. How can I make this trigger to work for all the 3 needs? I don't want to write multiple of triggers to handle this.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION sum_total() RETURNS TRIGGER
AS $$
BEGIN
    UPDATE payment
    SET price = price + (SELECT SUM(price) from basket WHERE service_id = new.service_id)
    WHERE service_id = new.service_id;
    RETURN NULL;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER sum_total AFTER INSERT ON basket
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE sum_total();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Postgres trigger function has a set of [special local  variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/plpgsql-trigger.html) made available to it. One of these, `TG_OP` indicates the action being that caused the trigger to fire. With this the basic template for multiple becomes:

```
create function trigger_function_name() 
  returns trigger
  language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    case TG_OP
         when 'INSERT'   then  
              <place code for insert processing here>
         when 'UPDATE'   then 
              <place code for update processing here>         
         when 'DELETE'   then
              <place code for delete processing here>         
         when 'TRUNCATE' then 
              <place code for truncate processing here>   -- note must be Statement level trigger        
    end ; 
    return new; 
end ; 
$$ ;
```

However, I advise against even attempting this. Keeping a running total quickly becomes complex. This is especially when the value you are trying to maintain is easily deliverable as:  
`select sum(price) from basket where service_id =  service_id_parameter;` 

That brings up another point. Your algorithm for computing `payment` is fundamentally flawed and *will not work* as is. Consider a user who adds an item to their basket at a price of 10. The payment price would not be 10 (what happens if this is the 1st item? Does the `payment` entry even exist for that `service_id`?) Now at a later time that user adds a second item for say 20. Total now in `basket` is now 30 (10+20), but value in `payment` is 40 (10 + sum(10,20)). And what happens to another user with the same items but selects them in the reverse order. (Hint, you will get a different `payment` value.) 
**Best process:** Unless you are expecting 100s of millions just eliminate the triggers altogether and derive the `payment` when needed, perhaps with a view that does so.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify different event types using `OR`
from the docs:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-createtrigger.html

```
event
One of INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or TRUNCATE; this specifies the 
event that will fire the trigger.
Multiple events can be specified using OR.
```

Comment: I know that. but when I delete the trigger wont remove the sum.